# Saving two or multiple records at the same time with a foreign key relation in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am creating an application manages an interview process. In one interview, a candidate can be interviewed by one or more interviewer and an interviewer can interview one or more candidates. This is similar to a "round table" interview. The simplified version of the models are:

```
class Interviewer(models.Model):
    interviewer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    candidates = models.ManyToManyField('Candidate', through='Interview')

class Candidate(models.Model):
    candidate_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False

class Interview(models.Model):
    interview_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    candidates = models.ForeignKey(
        Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='candidates')
    interviewers = models.ForeignKey(
        Interviewer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='interviewers')
```

In Django admin, for the Interview model, adding an entry for an interview would mean that I would have to create the entry for each candidate and interviewer. This process is cumbersome if there are a lot of candidates and/or interviewers. What I would like to do is to add all candidates and the interviewers for a particular interview.
I changed my model to use ModelMultipleChoiceField form instead of the default SelectField for Django uses for Foreign Keys.

```
class InterviewAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    interviewers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Interviewer.objects.all(),
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name='interviewers', is_stacked=False
        )
    )

    candidates = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Candidate.objects.all(),
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name='candidates', is_stacked=False
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Interview
        fields = '__all__'    

@admin.register(Interview)
class InterviewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = InterviewAdminForm
```

This now displays a ModelMultipleChoiceField with a FilteredSelectMultiple widget which I can use to select the candidates and interviewers for a particular interview.

The problem is when I click on save it shows the following error

```
Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Candidate: 11111111(John Doe)>, <Candidate: 22222222(Mary Moe)>]>": "Interview.candidates" must be a "Candidate" instance.
```

I reckon that it is getting all the candidates I chose from the ModelMultipleChoiceField as a query set and trying to add it to the database.

How can I instruct Django admin to add it as 2 separate records?

**Edit: To make my question clearer**

I am looking for a shorthand way to auto add multiple records as per my model definition.
Also, if my model definition isn't correct for what I would like to achieve, it would be great if you could provide me with a correct model definition. 
Hopefully this isn't asking two questions in one.

Comment: Can you clarify, your ploblem is that " I have to create the entry for each candidate and interviewer" but you want to find a way to "add it as 2 separate records". is it that you just are looking for s shorthand way to auto add multiple records? i.e. a record for every possible combination or a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @noone392  I am looking for a shorthand way to auto add multiple records as per my model definition. I edited my question to clarify my problem